# A C daemon that does traffic shaping

Tags: c, linux, networking, trafficshaping

I'm working on a C daemon that monitors a configuration file (updated using a web interface) and then uses the Linux "tc" (traffic control) command to update the systems traffic shaping configuration.

What's a good way to actually invoke the tc program? Should I use the exec family? Is there a library I can use that would be a bit more elegant? Using exec or system just seems a bit hacky to me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you look at the source code of the *tc* program and figure out how to modify the *systems traffic shaping configuration* directly from your deamon? That would save you calling *tc* and parsing it's output.

Comment: I have looked it over a bit...it uses netlink socket API which I dislike working with. I was hoping there would be a better/easier way. Maybe just a fantasy :)

Answer (score 1):

Look at popen http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen